# Remove Square brackets in postgresql (SQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have a date column that reads as string value [2018/04/09].i want to read it as date column 2018/04/09.How to do it in postgresql?

Comment: `DATE` columns do not contain `[` or `]` - in fact they do not contain any formatting at all. Is that column in fact defined as `varchar`? (which is a huge mistake to begin with)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, it could also be an array, which when viewed through a db client shows the open/close brackets.

Comment: @HaleemurAli: the default display of arrays in Postgres uses curly braces: `{..}` not square brackets.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, you are correct, i got confused with json arrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the function [`to_date`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html) with the date formatter.

Include additional string characters that appear on all dates as part of the format string, and the date can be parsed correctly.

```
WITH example (dt) AS (
VALUES ('[2018/04/09]')
)
SELECT to_date(dt, '[YYYY/MM/DD]') FROM example
```

Alternatively, if the object is to clean up the data as well, e.g. some dates have the square brackets while other dates don't, then it is better to replace all invalid characters and then parse as date.

example:

```
WITH example (dt) AS (
VALUES ('[2018/04/09]')
) 
SELECT to_date(trim(both '[]' from dt), 'YYYY/MM/DD') FROM example
```

Comment: i want to remove square brackets [2018/04/09] .Expected o/p 2018/04/09

Comment: what error do you get if you run my example. both of the examples above should return a properly parsed date. Please share the error message you get if you run my examples

Comment: to remove brackets SELECT substring('[2018/04/09]' from '\[(.*)\]')

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(date_column, 'YYYY/MM/DD') as date
FROM tablename
```

Comment: getting an error 'Detail: Value must be an integer'

Comment: can you share what query you are running and what is the table schema?